# Connecting to Office365 via a Proxy server

Tags: c#, powershell, office365

I need to connect to Office365 portal using powershell via a proxy server. I read an article [here](https://www.cogmotive.com/blog/office-365-tips/connecting-to-office-365-using-powershell-through-a-web-proxy-server) which says calling:

```
New-PSSessionOption -ProxyAccessType IEConfig
```

with IEConfig should do the trick.

But, is there a way that I can give proxy server without having to rely on IEConfig. i.e is there any other way to generate a -ProxyAccessType ? Something on the lines

```
$proxyserver = New-Object ProxyAccessType(server ip ...)
```

and then use the proxyserver in `New-PSSessionOption -ProxyAccessType $proxyserver`

Comment: I also spent some time on how to do this, but didn't find a solution

Comment: oh .. so using IEConfig is the only way? is it not a unnecessary limitation?

Comment: yes, so far I don't see any limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849703.aspx the supported values are
IEConfig, WinHttpConfig, AutoDetect, NoProxyServer and None. The default value is None.

WinHTTPConfig can be set using netsh http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731131%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

AutoDetect will use the wpad protocol to determine proxy settings http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol which can be kludged with a wpad file

Good Luck!

Comment: this does not exactly help me create powershell objects that could be used in variables but nevertheless provides a way to configure proxy using winhttpconfig. Thanks for the reply.